# ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout

Tags: android, admob

I received:

```
ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout
```

from google crash report. Strange fact is: I dont use ActivoBar. In fact my app was written for android 2.2 and up. Because of admob I have to add

android:targetSdkVersion=13

After this I had to add "android-support-v4.jar" because of

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Program works fine for my device and emulator but after release on market : - 400 reports about crash. /About 90% ot updated apps/

Hot to solve problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm. Problem was produced by different Dialog layout - in android ver 2.2 and 3.2 and up.
Custom dialog style for progress bar produced crash. Reason was misisng parent atribute in style. Strange but fact.

Comment: Which attribute was missing?

Answer (score 14):

you have to set parent attribute like below

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: Thanks to this post I found out I had theme for styles sdk v21 and not all of them and I was testing on v16, where I got this problem.